# How to filter from a series of numeric values (including NaN) to keep only the numbers that start with a specific digit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following series:

| Num |
| --- |
| 54321 |
| NaN |
| 1234 |
| 1325 |
| 92843 |

I want to keep the numbers starting with 1 only and the output should look like this:

| Num |
| --- |
| 1234 |
| 1325 |

I tried converting the numeric series to string and then use str.startswith('1), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try via boolean masking :

```
mask=(df['Num'].notna()) & (df['Num'].astype(str).str[0].eq('1'))
#Finally:
df[mask]
#OR
df.loc[mask]
```

output:

```
    Num
2   1234.0
3   1325.0
```

**Update:**

For *keep the numbers only when there are 5 digits in the number* mask become :

```
df['Num']=df['Num'].astype(str).str.strip('.0')
mask=(df['Num'].ne('nan') & df['Num'].str[0].eq('1')) & df['Num'].str.len().eq(5)
```

Comment: I have another question: How can I keep the numbers only when there are 5 digits in the number?

Comment: @EkaraiGlass including decimal?

Comment: @AnuragDabas OP don't have decimals in question, so I think we can negate decimals?

Comment: len(str(df['Num'])) did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @EkaraiGlass updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: @AnuragDabas I have taken a look. Yours is a more elegant solution. Thanks again!!

Comment: @EkaraiGlass Sir if your query is solved then you can try considering accepting the answer....thanks **:)**